# It appears that multiple Phusion Passenger instances are running

Tags: node.js, apache, passenger, centos6

I wanted to restart my node app so when I typed the passenger command to restart it ....It told me there are multiple instances of passenger running.

What I don't undertand is I only have one node application(which  in the code I configure to listen to the same port of it passenger I set in Passengerfile.json) and I installed passenger once how come it has 2 instances, then I put it behing an ssl terminating apache reverse proxy.

How can I know the use of each instances and which one is for my app?
Here is the out put of the command:

```
passenger-config restart-app
```

> It appears that multiple Phusion Passenger instances are running.
>   Please select a specific one by passing:
>
> --instance
>
> The following Phusion Passenger instances are running:
>
> Name                       PID      Description
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- xeqhHKNg                   2147     nginx/1.12.2
>   Phusion_Passenger/5.1.12 lHcUe3dD                   5866
>   nginx/1.12.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.12

I really want to understand what's going on.

Here is my configuration in Passengerfile.json :

```
{
  // Tell Passenger that this is a Node.js app.
  // Replace "app.js" with your app's entry point file.
  "app_type": "node",
 "address":"127.0.0.1",
 "startup_file": "bot.js",
  // Run the app in a production environment. The default value is "development".
  "environment": "production",
  // Run Passenger on the given port. In this example, we use port 80,
  // the standard HTTP port.
  "port": 3001,
  // Tell Passenger to daemonize into the background.
  "daemonize": true,
  // Tell Passenger to run the app as the given user. Only has effect
  // if Passenger was started with root privileges.
  "user": "kaku"
  }
```

And then the port of my node app is :

webserver.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, null, function() {

```
debug('Express webserver configured and listening at http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT || 3001);});
```

My http on centos 6 apache configuration :

```
#Redirecting all the non secured request to be secured 
     Redirect permanent / https://www.example.net/
```

My https(ssl) on centos 6 apache configuration :

```
  # Tells Apache to forward all requests for www.foo.com
    # to the Passenger Standalone instance listening on port 3001.
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
```

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue, you should post more details about your setup.

Comment: Which more information should I post?

Comment: For example, how did you install Passenger (there is more than one way), how did you configure it (Passengerfile.json), and how did you configure your ssl terminating apache proxy? Also you say that you configured the app to use the same port as Passenger, that's not good and will create a conflict.